# passing two arguements to lambda python

Tags: python

i want to do a simple list manipulation in python:
here is the way i did it using two for loops:

```
lst = []
coins = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]
maxi = 200
lst = lst + [0]*(maxi+5)
lst[0] = 1

for c in coins:
    for i in range(c, maxi+2):
        lst[i] += lst[i-c]
```

the above code gives me desired results, now i try to convert the two line loop into a one-liner

```
add = lambda i, c: lst[i] += lst[i-c]
[add(i, c) for i in range(c, maxi+1) for c in coins]
```

but i am getting an invalid syntax error, how can i pass the two variables `c` and `i` to lambda
and then manipulate the list at the two indexes.

Which is a more pythonic way of doing it?

Can anyone suggest shorter code?

**I want to use only list comprehension. How can i implement the above code using list comprehension?**

Comment: Python lambdas only support expressions that return a result. `lst[i] += lst[i-c]` is a statement (with a side effect) but not an expression, so that's why you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: is there any way i could do with only the list comprehension??

Comment: List comprehension will most likely be slower than your nested loops? Why are you doing this?

Comment: user993563: @SvenMarnach's answer does give a way to solve the problem using a list comprehension. However, he is entirely right that it is unnecessary and unpythonic.

Comment: @gnibbler i am doing it for fun, how much slower some 10 microseconds, i dont give a damn about microseconds.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: where could i find the definition of "Pythonic"??

Comment: for definition of Pythonic `import this`

Comment: Setting aside questions of pythonicity, the purpose of list comprehensions is to create lists. Using them as a flow control structure is a) confusing, b) contrary to their declarative nature, and c) wasteful of resources.

Comment: @gnibbler the clauses are subjective. I go by the first clause: Beautiful is better than ugly.   List comprehensions are more b'ful to me than two ugly loops.

Comment: It's your code. But if you think a for loop is "ugly", you're misunderstanding the doctrine.

Comment: Actually, there is an excellent StackOverflow question on precisely this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: @DavidRobinson   thnx, i was a newbie, amazd by more complicated looking comprehension, that post explains stuff.

Comment: @user993563: indeed, we all start as beginners, and we've all been there :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the double loop you have is perfectly fine -- why do you want a shorter version?

The error you get is because you put a *statement* inside a lambda function, where only expressions are allowed.  You *could* write this as a list comprehension -- something like (untested)

```
[lst.__setitem__(i, lst[i] + lst[i - c]) 
 for c in coins for i in range(c, maxi+1)]
```

but seriously -- why should you?  Apart from being obscure, it also creates a pointless long list of `None` values.

The only thing I'd change about your code is the initialisation of `lst`, which is strangely spread out over three lines.  The following line will be enough:

```
lst = [1] + [0] * (maxi + 4)
```

Comment: @user993563, does it, really?

Comment: Using a list comprehension when a for loop would work faster and better doesn't look cool to me.

Comment: `lst = [0] *(maxi +5)` `lst[0] = 1` would be probably a better idea, as it avoids creating unnecesary lists and copying them

Comment: @soulcheck: Since the list at hand has length 200, I don't think this is an issue.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah, I just mentioned it just in case someone stumbles upon this question with a greater `maxi`

Answer (score 2):

That's because `+=` in python is a statement, not an expression - it doesn't return any value.  lambdas must contain only expressions in python.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a list comprehension for this- it is more Pythonic just to do

```
for c in coins:
    for i in range(c, maxi + 1):
        lst[i] += lst[i - c]
```

ETA: The reason is that list comprehensions are meant to be used for function that return values (thus ending up with a list)- it is unnecessary (and violates [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) practices) to use them with a function that has side effects.